# How should I store JSON in redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I have JSON (<1k) to store in Redis through node.js. What are the pros and cons of storing it as an object or string? Are there other options I missed? All processing will ultimately happen on the client side, so converting into an object is not necessary.

**SET**

```
var images = JSON.parse(data);          // data is already JSON, is this needed?
callback(images);                       // sends result to the user
r.set('images:' + req.query, images);   // saving the object
```

**GET**

```
callback(images);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can store JSON in redis either as a plain string in dedicated key (or member/value of a set/list) or in a [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) structure. If you look at [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) docs into **Friendlier hash commands** part you'll see that it gives you some useful methods for manipulating JSON based data. Pros of this approach is that it allows you to get/set only part of the original object and it might also [consume less memory](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage) compared to plain strings.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the con of the hash structure is that retrieval is much slower, since you would have to iterate through the each field to reconstruct the original.

Comment: You can retrieve the entire hash with HGETALL command and although it's time complexity is O(n) I think the performance would be visibly affected only with large amounts of field/value pairs.

Comment: The link for riendlier hash commands https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#friendlier-hash-commands

Comment: and what happens if i strip all the json keys and store the values as a csv plain string, wouldnt that be the fastest approach, example instead of storing {name: "John", age: 42} in stringified format, i store "John,42"

Answer (score 10):

The [RedisJSON](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/) module allows storing, updating and fetching JSON values from Redis keys.

It adds a new JSON datatype and commands to Redis which can be accessed like any other Redis native commands.

e.g.

```sh
> JSON.SET user1 $ '{"name":"Ron Dan", "lastSeen":1478476800, "loggedOut": true}'
OK

> JSON.GET user1 $.name
"[\"Ron Dan\"]"

> JSON.NUMINCRBY user1 $.lastSeen 100
"[1478476900]"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use this library [redis-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-json)

Sample usage example:

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import JSONCache from 'redis-json';

const redis = new Redis();

const jsonCache = new JSONCache(redis)

const user = {
  name: "test",
  age: 21,
  gender: "male"
}
await jsonCache.set('123', user)

const result = await jsonCache.get('123')
```

This library stores the json in Hash set.

It also supports retreival of a single or a set of keys, i.e.

```
await jsonCache.get('123', "age", "name")
```

Comment: seems like something is off
```(node:63245) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: redis_json_1.default is not a constructor
```

Comment: I have been messing around with redis-json for 3 days now and now dumped it. Could not get rid of the redis_json_1.default is not a constructor problem.
The library is also way to slow with huge json (5MB airport list) because it flattens the data. You can use the redis object to directly store and get data. Just write 

await redis.set('key',JSON.stringify(data))
 
to store data and 

await redis.get('key') 

to retrieve the json string again. That simple.

Comment: is there a way to filter on a JSON field? eg `{gender: 'male' }`

Comment: Not at the moment and I don't think that going to happen anytime in the future too because redis is merely a key-value store and not a full fledge DB.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i stored json in redis cache

```
 Models.Student.findAll({
        where: {
            id : req.params.id
        }
    }).then(doc => {
        client.setex(req.params.id, 3600, doc);
        res.send(200, doc);
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        res.send(400, err);
    });
```